# What is the correct phrase for ex-in-laws when divorced?

Tags: terminology, kinship-terms

If you get divorced, are your ex-spouse's siblings' children still your nieces or nephews?

Comment: I think it depends entirely on whether you want them to be. The terms uncle and aunt have no legal significance, after all.

Comment: I think it depends mostly on how well you get along w/ your ex-family tree. There's no strict rule, same as there's no rule that your sister/brother-in-law cannot remain an in-law just because you divorced.

Comment: That depends whether both of you have had children together, who would have no choice as you would.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Having children with your ex spouse's siblings' children is beyond even Woody Allen.

Comment: Spehro, trying to be cute? Obviously I meant with your ex-spouse.

Comment: "I am your father's brother's nephew's cousin's **former** roommate." –[Spaceballs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZd_YyFzPD0)

Answer (score 0):

This all depends upon your view of family.

Many cultures view the extended family as belonging to one side or the other.  Many other cultures view the extended family as being married into and hence adopted by the spouse.  And, many cultures allow for a personal choice based upon your family's specific dynamic.

Some examples:

> I have a Columbian friend who tells me that he is Tio Juan (Uncle Juan) to his nieces and nephews, but his wife is merely Robyn (not Tia Robyn).
>
> To my wife's nephews I am Uncle Dave.  But, I still tend to refer to them as *her* nephews.
>
> I have a friend whose children I regard as being my nephews without any blood relationship.

That said, many other Americans would say that my wife's sisters' kids are my nephews, too.  But, I would say that doesn't exactly match our family dynamic.

So, as there is no legal definition, go with your gut.  There is plenty of precedent with every variety.

My personal usage would be:  *My ex's nieces and nephews.*  Or if I were still close to them, *my nieces and nephews*.

Comment: My wife is of Chinese descent. They do not stick with simple concepts like aunt, uncle, niece, nephew. My mother-in-law was one of 13 children. Now every aunt and uncle, whether blood relative or by marriage is individually described. Thus there is a word which means 'my mother's third eldest sister's husband', 'my mother's younger brother's wife' etc. Even brothers and sisters use honorifics. Younger siblings have a special word 'zher,zher' (in Cantonese) meaning 'older sister', and kor, kor (older brother). Divorce would be prohibitively complicated!

Comment: @WS2 That is as good of a reason to stay together as I've ever heard!  BTW - If you've never read it, can I recommend a children's book Tikki-tikki-tembo.  (Not to be confused with Riki-Tiki-Tavi.)  It's not quite the same concept, but still cute in that regard.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't, though I've often meant to. We have a young birthday coming up so its given me an idea of something to add to the 'stocking'.

Comment: @WS2 I would preview it, it doesn't read as racist to me, but perhaps someone else could perceive it that way.

Comment: Our own children's racial innocence was never compromised by  having Little Black Sambo read to them, so I can't think it will be a problem!

Answer (score 0):

Nieces and nephews are still your nieces and nephews but just not connected through your blood line. Whether you want to continue a relationship with them depends on your relationship while you were married to their blood related uncle/aunt. If you have children then the blood link is tied to that generation not you. However, I do believe that brothers and sisters-in-law are no longer called 'in-laws' as the term "in-law" relates to the law of your marriage to their brother/sister. When the bond of marriage is broken with your spouse it is broken with the 'in-laws'. Your choice to continue in friendship is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce any awkward moment I would introduce my ex in-laws as this " ...introduce you to John and Hazel Smith, they are my ex-husband Todd's parents", which hereby explains the connection and eliminates any complication. This method would explain all ex situations, e.g., my ex-husband's niece, my ex-husband's sister, etc.